# How can I query data from multiple tables connected through foreign keys?

Tags: php, html, sql, oracle

I have a [Search page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDL2U.png) where users can search based on certain criteria. I cannot get the query right to display only one of the desired objects. It is displaying multiple entries for specified criteria. Here is our database setup:

```
CREATE TABLE Class
    (       
        cid int NOT NULL,
        classNum int,
        classDept varchar(20),
        PRIMARY KEY (cid)
    );

CREATE TABLE Book
    (
        bid int NOT NULL,
        cid int NOT NULL,
        title varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
        author varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        isbn varchar(13),
        price decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (bid),
        FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES Class (cid)
    );

CREATE TABLE Contact
    (
        contactID int NOT NULL,
        fname varchar(20),
        lname varchar(20),
        contactInfo varchar(90) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (contactID)
    );

CREATE TABLE Post
    (
        pid int NOT NULL,
        contactID int NOT NULL,
        bid int NOT NULL,
        postDate date,
        PRIMARY KEY (pid),
        FOREIGN KEY (contactID) references Contact(contactID),
        FOREIGN KEY (bid) references Book(bid)
    );
```

Here is the php code we are using to try to query based on criteria the user has entered.

```
$author = $_POST["author"];
     $title = $_POST["title"];
     $classNum = $_POST["number"];
     $classDept = $_POST["department"];
     $isbn = $_POST["isbn"];


              $query = "SELECT title, author, isbn, price, classNum, classDept, contactInfo
           FROM Book, Class, Contact, Post
           WHERE Book.cid=Class.cid AND Contact.contactID=Post.ContactID and Book.bid=Post.bid AND Book.author='$author' OR Book.title='$title' ";
     $stid = oci_parse($conn,$query);
     oci_execute($stid,OCI_DEFAULT);
```

What are we doing wrong? How can we get the proper search results to display?

Comment: Please provide some data and a sample of the query results that you consider to be wrong. Also an explanation of why you think that it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that the join syntax in Oracle is the same as mysql ( which is what this was built and tested in ) but given the dummy data and minor modifications to some tables ( adding auto_increment to primary keys ) it returns the expected two rows that match the params.

```
create table if not exists `book` (
  `bid` int(11) not null auto_increment,
  `cid` int(11) not null,
  `title` varchar(64) not null,
  `author` varchar(20) not null,
  `isbn` varchar(13) default null,
  `price` decimal(5,2) not null,
  primary key (`bid`),
  key `cid` (`cid`),
  constraint `book_ibfk_1` foreign key (`cid`) references `class` (`cid`)
) engine=innodb auto_increment=5 default charset=utf8;

insert into `book` (`bid`, `cid`, `title`, `author`, `isbn`, `price`) values
    (1, 1, 'deranged dahlias', 'gertrude geikel', '1234-cdbs-9d', 250.00),
    (2, 1, 'mental magnolias', 'gertrude geikel', '4234-cdfg-9f', 225.00),
    (3, 1, 'raging roses', 'gertrude geikel', '4389-fkpl-8d', 120.25),
    (4, 3, 'peaceful petunias', 'alice cooper', '9043-dflk-01', 500.25);

create table if not exists `class` (
  `cid` int(11) not null auto_increment,
  `classnum` int(11) default null,
  `classdept` varchar(20) default null,
  primary key (`cid`)
) engine=innodb auto_increment=4 default charset=utf8;

insert into `class` (`cid`, `classnum`, `classdept`) values
    (1, 404, 'fookology'),
    (2, 403, 'forbidden fruits'),
    (3, 200, 'goodness');

create table if not exists `contact` (
  `contactid` int(11) not null auto_increment,
  `fname` varchar(20) default null,
  `lname` varchar(20) default null,
  `contactinfo` varchar(90) not null,
  primary key (`contactid`)
) engine=innodb auto_increment=3 default charset=utf8;

insert into `contact` (`contactid`, `fname`, `lname`, `contactinfo`) values
    (1, 'joe', 'bloggs', 'chief headbanger'),
    (2, 'fred', 'flintstone', 'potatopeeler');

create table if not exists `post` (
  `pid` int(11) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `contactid` int(11) not null,
  `bid` int(11) not null,
  `postdate` date default null,
  primary key (`pid`),
  key `contactid` (`contactid`),
  key `bid` (`bid`),
  constraint `post_ibfk_1` foreign key (`contactid`) references `contact` (`contactid`),
  constraint `post_ibfk_2` foreign key (`bid`) references `book` (`bid`)
) engine=innodb auto_increment=3 default charset=utf8;

insert into `post` (`pid`, `contactid`, `bid`, `postdate`) values
    (1, 1, 1, '2015-12-02'),
    (2, 2, 4, '2015-12-02');
```

Query run in mysql gui - not sure if the join syntax is the same in oracle .

```
set @_author='alice cooper';
set @_title='mental magnolias';

select * from `book` b
    left outer join `class` c on c.`cid`=b.`cid`
    left outer join `post` p on p.`bid`=b.`bid`
    left outer join `contact` ct on ct.`contactID`=p.`contactID`
    where b.`title`=@_title or b.`author`=@_author;
```

Or, for php

```
$author=$_POST['author'];
$title=$_POST['title'];

$sql="select * from `book` b
    left outer join `class` c on c.`cid`=b.`cid`
    left outer join `post` p on p.`bid`=b.`bid`
    left outer join `contact` ct on ct.`contactID`=p.`contactID`
    where b.`title`='{$title}' or b.`author`='{$author}';";
```